# Implementing a wall jump procedure when the player collides with a wall

Tags: python, pygame

I hope that someone can help me or give me some advice with my problem.
I have been playing around with the pygame module for python and I have come across a problem that I can not seem to solve.
What I would like to happen is:

- The user collides with the wall.
- The user inputs a jump command.
- The player objects jumps then falls.
- Can be repeated.

The problem is however is that in my code that player can just hold "Up Arrow" and "Left Arrow" and constantly fly upwards, which I do not wish to happen, and I do not know how to get around this. I have made many attempts all of which are in vain.

This is the full code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 800
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

MAPLIST = ["LevelOne.txt"]
MAPCOUNT = 0

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)
    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h
    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#f21000"))

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)

        #self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png")
        #self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.canJump = False
        self.wallCollide = False

    def jump(self):

        if self.onGround:
            self.yvel = 0
            self.yvel -= 8
            self.rect.top += self.yvel
            self.onGround=False
            self.canJump=False

        if self.canJump and not self.onGround:
            self.yvel = 0
            self.yvel -= 4
            self.rect.top += self.yvel
            self.onGround = False
            self.canJump = False

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms,entities):
        if self.wallCollide and not self.onGround:

        if down:
            print(self.wallCollide)
        if up:
            self.jump()
        if running:
            self.xvel = 1
        if left:
            self.xvel = -4
        if right:
            self.xvel = 4

        if not self.onGround:
                # print("x")
                # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
                # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100:
                self.yvel = 100

        if not (left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms, entities)
        # increment in y direction
        if not self.onGround:
            self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0,self.yvel, platforms, entities)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms, entities):
        # Player collisions with platforms. e.g. main blocks
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if yvel == 0:
                    self.wallCollide = True
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left  # collide right
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right  # collide left
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.canJump = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
                    # if isinstance(p,Platform):
                    # self.onGround = True

class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("brick.png")
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

def LoadMap(platforms,entities,x,y):
    currentLevel=[]
    mapFile = open(MAPLIST[MAPCOUNT])
    for line in mapFile:
        currentLevel.append(line)

    for row in currentLevel:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            elif col == "X":
                player=Player(x,y)
                entities.add(player)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0
    return currentLevel, player

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Super Meat Boy")
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 40)
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    platforms = []

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    x = y = 0

    bg = Surface((32, 32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#66ccff"))
    currentLevel,player = LoadMap(platforms,entities,x,y)

    total_level_width = len(currentLevel[0]) * 32
    total_level_height = len(currentLevel) * 32
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)

    while True:
        clock=timer.tick(60)
        for e in pygame.event.get():

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = False

        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        camera.update(player)

        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms, entities)

        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))


        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the part of the code where the issues are:

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)

        #self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png")
        #self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.canJump = False
        self.wallCollide = False

    def jump(self):
        if self.onGround:
            self.yvel = 0
            self.yvel -= 8
            self.rect.top += self.yvel
            self.onGround=False
            self.canJump=False

        if self.canJump and not self.onGround:
            self.yvel = 0
            self.yvel -= 4
            self.rect.top += self.yvel
            self.onGround = False
            self.canJump = False

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms, entities):
        if self.wallCollide and not self.onGround:

        if down:
            print(self.wallCollide)
        if up:
            self.jump()
        if running:
            self.xvel = 1
        if left:
            self.xvel = -4
        if right:
            self.xvel = 4

        if not self.onGround:
                # print("x")
                # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
                # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100:
                self.yvel = 100

        if not (left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms, entities)
        # increment in y direction
        if not self.onGround:
            self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0,self.yvel, platforms, entities)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms, entities):
        # Player collisions with platforms. e.g. main blocks
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if yvel == 0:
                    self.wallCollide = True
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left  # collide right
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right  # collide left
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.canJump = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
                    # if isinstance(p,Platform):
                    # self.onGround = True
```

So in conclusion I do not wish for the player to be able to fly up the wall when they hold the "up arrow". Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

(Sorry if I have posted this in the incorrect format or place, I am new to this site.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a coding answer, but more of a design one.

One common design for wall-jumping in video games involves automatically giving the character a 'push' to the side when wall-jumping. Consider the Megaman X series -- if you jump onto the right wall and jump off, it pushes you to the left. You can still hold right to keep bouncing off the wall, but you can't zoom up the wall.

So my suggestion would be to make walljumps a special type of jump, where you give their `xvel` a sharp boost in the direction opposite the wall.

Alternately, put a limit on how often the character can walljump. Maybe a walljump flips a flag that prevents further walljumps for a set number of frames.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am attempting to use your suggestion to make the character "bounce" off the wall, but I have made the character move in the opposite direction, but it is still detecting a collision as the player will be holding, for example the [Left Arrow] so the  program moves the character to the right when he hits the wall, but since they are holding left arrow, almost instantaneously it just makes a little hop flying upwards. Do you have any other idea on how achieve this? It might have helped if I said that I was aiming for a super meat boy esc style of game. Thanks again.